# Defining declared variable outside of my class

Tags: php, class

I have a class where I first do a SQL check to see if some certain data exist and if not then I INSERT a new record.

I'd like to somehow define a variable ($feedback) indicating ive either inserted something or havent - I want to use this var in a callback in my main PHP file (where ive included the class)

**My class**

```
class registerVote {

function registerVote(){

}

function init() {
    //Define some vars  
    return true;
}

function save() {
        //Sql count query
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
        $count = mysql_result($res, 0); 

        //If no records are found then INSERT
        if($count < 1){
            //Some INSERT query
            $feedback = "new";
        } else {
            $feedback = "old";
        }

    if($res) {
        return $feedback;
    }
}

}
```

My PHP FILE:

```
include_once ('../class/class_vote.php');
$registerVote = new registerVote();

    if($registerVote->init()) {
        if($registerVote->save()) {
            //Print out my $feedback from the class
        if ($feedback == "new") {
            echo "new";
        } else {
            echo "old";
        }
        }
    }
```

The above naturally doesnt work - so im naturally wondering if im able to achieve what ive tried to illustrate?

Answer (score 2):

Just capture the return value:

```
include_once ('../class/class_vote.php');
$registerVote = new registerVote();

if($registerVote->init()) {
    $feedback = $registerVote->save();
    if($feedback) {
        //Print out my $feedback from the class
        if ($feedback == "new") {
            echo "new";
        } else {
            echo "old";
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, `save()` should always return something.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your `registerVote::save()` function return the `$feedback`. That seems like a reasonable way of doing it.

Minor: if `$res` is `false` the `or die` case will have triggered and your script will exit, the `if` around the `return` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

return the value to be assigned.

Or

Set the value on a static property of an object.

```
class Feedback {
    static public $results;
}
```

then you can call

```
Feedback::$results = "new";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correctly returning `$feedback` but you should consider returning a `boolean`, `true` or `false` for example. You need to store the return of the `$registerVote->save()` call, though, and then you can check it. You could also change your `init` function to `__construct`, that way you don't have to call it. Your class will be like this:

```
class registerVote
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //Define some vars  
        return true;
    }

    public function registerVote()
    {
    }

    public function save()
    {
        //Sql count query
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
        $count = mysql_result($res, 0); 

        if($count === 0)
        {
            // store some stuff.
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
   }
}
```

Your PHP file would be like this:

```
include_once ('../class/class_vote.php');
$registerVote = new registerVote();

if($registerVote->save())
{
    echo "New!";
}
else
{
    echo "Old!";
}
```